# Are fences enough for protecting village from raids?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to cover my Minecraft village with cobblestone fences to protect my village from raids. Is it enough? Will some mobs in raids jump fences and attack my Minecraft village?

I'm afraid that pillagers will shoot arrows to the villager and golems. Is there any better way to defend the village?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a funny note, you can check out this video for different ways to protect villagers from pillagers during a raid [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3-par3l9m8).

On a serious note, yes and no. While pillagers cannot jump a cobblestone fences, they will still shoot at villagers if they can see them. According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pillager#Behavior):

> They [Pillagers] shoot an arrow every 3 seconds up to 8 blocks away, following the foe for up to 12 blocks.

If you make your cobblestone wall three blocks high or higher, it should be high enough to prevent pillagers and ravagers from seeing the villagers at all and trying to shoot them.

Comment: Although it may waste resources, but thanks anyway.